# Message Sent To Deallocated Instance When Using Tab Key Only

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have an view controller with a form like so:
[image]

When I use the back and forward buttons on the input accessory view, everything works fine. However, in simulator when I use the tab key on the keyboard to traverse the text fields, and then segue back to the previous view controller, I get the following:

[image]

and then this in the console:

[image]

I look for zombie objects in Instruments and find this:

[image]

but that doesn't provide much help. Any idea why this would ONLY happen when tab is pressed on the keyboard in simulator? It isn't an issue on the device and I can't reproduce it there but I feel like a zombie object needs to be address either way.

and here is my code for that view controller:

in viewDidLoad i'm calling setupInputAccessoryView

```
func setupInputAccessoryView(){
// Create a button bar for the number pad
let keyboardDoneButtonView = UIToolbar()
keyboardDoneButtonView.sizeToFit()

    // Setup the buttons to be put in the toolbar.
    let item4 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("endEditingNow") )
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " <  ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("previousField"))
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "  >", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("nextField"))
    let item3 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17) {
        item4.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    if let font2 = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 26){
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        item2.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    //Add buttons to toolbar and add as an inputAccessoryView
    var toolbarButtons = [item, item2, item3, item4]
    keyboardDoneButtonView.setItems(toolbarButtons, animated: false)
    keyBoardToolBar = keyboardDoneButtonView
}
```

and then in textFieldDidBeginEditing I have:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    currentTextField = textField
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar

    if (textField == stateField){
        statePicker.frame = CGRectZero
        statePicker.delegate = self
        statePicker.dataSource = self
        textField.inputView = statePicker

    }else if (textField == countryField){
        countryPicker.frame = CGRectZero
        countryPicker.delegate = self
        countryPicker.dataSource = self
        textField.inputView = countryPicker
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.scrollView.contentOffset.y = textField.center.y - 30

    })

}
```

and then my selectors for the toolbar buttons

```
func endEditingNow(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


func nextField(){
    var nextTag = currentTextField!.tag + 1
    self.view.viewWithTag(nextTag)?.becomeFirstResponder()
}


func previousField(){
    var nextTag = currentTextField!.tag - 1
    self.view.viewWithTag(nextTag)?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: You have to show some of your code otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Are you using notifications?

Comment: I guess the issue is that I'm not sure what class to post. I'm not even sure where the error is occurring. I get no information here. It's crashing AFTER I unwind and AFTER viewDidAppear on the view controller I'm unwinding to. I thought it was a 3rd party library I'm using called DAKeyboardControl but I've removed that and the issue still persists so I really don't know what's happening. I AM using notifications but I'm removing observer on viewWillDisappear so I don't think that's it but I honestly have no idea now. I find it odd that it ONLY happens when TAB is pressed on the keyboard

Comment: What i've discovered is that if I remove the line: textField.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar...the issue is gone but then I won't have an input accessory view on my keyboard.